# Access(checkall, uncheck, middlestate) to dynamic checkbox in asp table via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I'm trying to write privilige group checkbox. Something like 
[this](http://scr.hu/0r52/7642x)

So far I made page where I put empty control made by me which looks like this

```
<fieldset>
  <legend><asp:CheckBox ID="GroupName" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" text="test" onclick="checkAll()"/></legend>
<span> <!--class="filterTableSpan"-->
<asp:Table ID="priviligeTable" runat="server" CssClass="groupTable">


</asp:Table>
</span>
</fieldset>
```

then I fill priviligeTable

```
CheckBox privilCheck = new CheckBox();
privilCheck.ID = this.ID + "_" + privName; //ID of group

TableCell tc = new TableCell();
tc.ID = this.ID + "_tc" + privName;
tc.Controls.Add(privilCheck);
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
tr.ID = this.ID + "_tr" + privName;
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
this.priviligeTable.Rows.Add(tr);
```

and now I'd like to make javascript for select all, unselect and mid state to Privilige Group Name checkbox, but I do not know how to access dynamic generated checkboxes. Furthermore I'm a newbie with javascript. I would be pleased if someone could show me a way to solve this problem or rather a direction which I should head to solve by my efforts this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these roles come from a list in a database? If so,  my instinct would be to avoid the  and use  instead. The Gridview gives you more built-in functionality including templates that enable you to create all the checkboxes on the go.

However, what you are doing could work too.

I suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) - it will make your life a lot easier and ensure your code works across all browsers.

Then you need something like this. This will toggle all the checkboxes on or off.

```
function checkAll() {
    // Find all the checkboxes in the table
    var $checkboxes = $('table.groupTable input[type=checkbox]');

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // Check them
        $checkboxes.attr("checked","checked");
    } else {
        // Uncheck them
        $checkboxes.removeAttr("checked",);
    }
}
```

I think that should do it. Not sure what you mean by 'mid-state' though. They are either checked or not.

Don't forget that on postback you need to recreate all the checkboxes to be able to read their contents.

Comment: Solved 
function check(GroupCheckbox) {
        var str = GroupCheckbox.id.replace("_PriviligeGroupCheckbox", "");
        var CurrentTable = document.getElementById(str  + "_priviligeTable");
        var name = "#"+str + "_priviligeTable";
            if (!GroupCheckbox.checked)
                $( name+' input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
            else
                $(name +' input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
but it would by impossible without your help Thank you Very much.

Comment: Nice one. Hard to read your answer but I assume it works! Note that if you're using jQuery you can replace document.getElementById('myCheckBox') with $('#myCheckBox') which makes your code more readable. 

Also I see you're trying to locate a table from the groupcheckbox that's been clicked. A better way might be to store the table's ID in the checkbox itself as a data attribute, i.e. `<input type="checkbox" ... data-tableid="cats_priviligeTable" >`. Then you can do `var currentTable = $('#'+$(this).data('tableid'))`. Etc. Good luck.

Comment: As 'mid-state' i make by asp.net property enabled=false; but clicking disabled checkbox not work at all